# How to create a user-defined spline implementation to be passed to a formula

Tags: r, data-modeling, bspline

I am creating a new modeling framework for nonparametric regression. The function `pspl` takes a one-dimensional vector of data, along with some additional complexity parameters, and returns a matrix of basis functions evaluated at the data. The goal is for this function to be used just like `ns` or `bs`, i.e., it should be passed to a modelling function like `lm` inside a formula. The function `pspl` comes with a `predict` method, which evaluates the set of basis function at some new data. Such a function is needed when predicting from a model that is fitted using `pspl`.

The fitting of a model works fine. Predicting on a new dataset unfortunately does not. The reason seems to be, that R does not find/use my function predict.pspl.

I am not super familiar with how to set up my own classes and methods, so some help would be much appreciated here.

```
library(fda)

pspl <- function(x, num.breaks = NULL, breaks = NULL, norder = 4){

  nx <- names(x)
  if(is.null(breaks)){
    breaks <- quantile(x, probs = seq(0,1,length.out = num.breaks))
    names(breaks) <- NULL
  } 
  basis <- create.bspline.basis(norder=norder, breaks=breaks)
  Z <- getbasismatrix(x, basis, nderiv=0, returnMatrix=FALSE)
  dimnames(Z) <- list(names(x), 1:ncol(Z))
  a <- list(num.breaks=num.breaks, breaks=breaks, norder=norder)
  attributes(Z) <- c(attributes(Z), a)
  class(Z) <- "pspl"
  Z
}

predict.pspl <- function(object, newx, ...){
  if(missing(newx)) 
    return(object)
  a <- c(list(x = newx), attributes(object)[c("breaks", "norder")])
  do.call("pspl", a)
}
```

Running example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 2*rnorm(100)
y <- sin(x) + .5*rnorm(100)
xnew <- rnorm(100)


mod <- lm(y ~ -1 + pspl(x, num.breaks = 5))
plot(x,y)
points(x,fitted(mod), col="blue") ## correct fit
points(xnew,predict(pspl(x, num.breaks = 5), xnew)%*%coef(mod), col="green") ## what should be predicted
points(xnew, predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x=xnew)), col="red") ## what is actually predicted
```

[black: data, blue: fit, green: correct prediction (done "by hand"), red: actual prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X0gP.png)